# 2d array search algorithm

Tags: python, java, algorithm, optimization, search

I am working in a project where I need to optimize the 2d array search time (It is just for context but my question is for the below paper).

While searching internet, I came across this research paper published in IJCAT:
https://www.ijcat.com/archives/volume5/issue1/ijcatr05011005.pdf

Here the author is using a grid approach to search the value by creating a grid , however my interpretation is it is still a sequential search.  I am not able to make sense out of it. I am not a very expert programmer. Can anyone help me in verifying that the claim author is making is legitimate. I am more interested in algorithm correctness rather than checking it by implementing it.

Comment: Can you say anything about the 2d array?  For example is it sorted?  If not, sequential search is the only thing that can work.

Comment: @btilly Actually I am not able to understand this paper.  How searching in grid can improve the search time.

Comment: That paper is ... crap in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments on that paper (ignoring bad grammar):

- In `LINEAR_SEARCH (M, NUM, n)` there is a final check `if (Flag == 0) then` which will always be true. In fact, there is no need for a `Flag`. Same is true for  `GRID_SEARCH (M, n, NUM)`
- In `RANGE (n)` the final return `(T * T)` is wrong. From how this function is used, it is clear the *intention* was to return `3 * T`. But this means this function always performs a division by 3 and then a multiplication by 3. Not to mention that `T MOD 3` is sometimes calculated twice. This is  not very smart. That function could just be:

  ```pascal
  R = N MOD 3
  if R == 0 then return T
            else return T + 3 - R
  ```
- `CHECK` is executed for **every** possible coordinate pair, on top of the checks that the `for` loops already do for their end-conditions.
- There is a note that says *"Here the order of nested If-Else condition is
  important"*, but there is not a single `else` in `GRID_SEARCH`. Secondly, the order is not important if there is no match, since all those `if` conditions will have to be evaluated.
- When `N` is not a multiple of 3, then there will be calls of `CHECK` that return `false`, but imagine that was because `j+1` is too large: then still the algorithm wastes time on calling `CHECK` again with `j+1` (with different `i` arguments).
- When `N` is not a multiple of 3, and no match is found (or only at the very end), there will be a a number of `CHECK` calls that return `false` that is either approximately 2N or 4N. There is no gain for this waste of effort.
- The author then shows statistics and functions  and  without showing what exactly these functions represent (they are just called "the function of the algorithm" -- very enlightening!), but I get a hunch the author is counting the number of iterations of the loops, but that would be an unfair comparison, since the body of the simple search algorithm performs much less work than the inner body of the grid-search loops.
- The graph in which these functions are displayed does not reveal more as the labels of the X and Y axes are just "X axis" and "Y axis". That doesn't really look professional, not to speak of whether it could be called scientific.

I would not spend another second on this paper.

When you have N values in a random order, and need to find a value, you can decide to fit those values in an array, or in a matrix, why not in a cube, ... but no matter how you turn it, the value you search could be *anywhere* in that collection. You don't increase your chances by visiting the values in another order than the rest of the world would do.